# How to create a multidimensional list using OOP in python?

Tags: python

For example,
I need to create a multidimensional list that has name and age of a person as shown below
person=[['pav',26],
               [ 'sunny',24]]

I want to create it using OOP concepts involving class and instance. I have written the code and i know there is some mistake in the syntax. Please tell me what is the mistake and how do I rectify it?

Below is the code I have written:

```
class persondata:
    def __init__(self,Name,Age):
        self.Name=Name
        self.Age=Age
person=[[],[]]
person[0]=persondata('pav',26)
person[1]=persondata('sunny',24)
print(person)
```

Comment: You need to do indent for both `self` lines.

Comment: I tried still not getting the output properly..it is showing the memory location but not printing the list

Answer (score 2):

Your creation is ok. If you want its string representation to look nice, add a `__repr__` function. For example:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return repr([self.Name, self.Age])
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried still not getting the output properly..it is showing the memory location but not printing the list

You can use [**str**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method to print the object value as you wish.

```
class persondata:
    def __init__(self,Name,Age):
        self.Name=Name
        self.Age=Age
    def __str__(self):
        return(",".join([self.Name,str(self.Age)]))
try:
    person=[[],[]]
    person[0]=persondata('pav',26)
    person[1]=persondata('sunny',24)
    print(*person)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Output:

```
pav,26 sunny,24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Intro:

    data = []
    def __init__(self):
        print ("Welcome")

    def add(self,name,age):
        self.data.append((name,age))

    def Display(self):
        for self.name,self.age in self.data:
            print(self.name+" "+str(self.age))

introduction =  Intro()
introduction.add("xyz",10)
introduction.add("pqr",20)
introduction.Display()
```

Output: 
       xyz 10
       pqr 20

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK but persondata is an object and when you print it you see the memory location.

Here is a more pythonic version of your code

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr([self.name, self.age])

people = []
people.append(Person('pav', 26))
people.append(Person('sunny', 24))
print(people)
```

Output:

```
[['pav', 26], ['sunny', 24]]
```